# Two NSArrays combine to a NSDictionary with alternating values

Tags: arrays, objective-c, dictionary, data-structures, concatenation

Hi I am very new to Objective-c please excuse my ignorance. So basically this is what I want to happened. I have two arrays of numbers

```
Array1: (1,3,5);
Array2: (2,4,6);
```

and I want them to be like this after combining them in a dictionary

```
"dictionary":{"1":2,: "3":4, "5":6}
```

Any feedback will be appreciated!

Comment: You just write a tiny tiny bit of code for that. It's quite trivial.

Comment: `dictionaryWithObjects:forKeys:`should do the job. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdictionary/1574183-dictionarywithobjects?language=objc

Answer (score 0):

### Arrays

> I have two arrays of numbers `Array1: (1,3,5)` & `Array2: (2,4,6)`

I assume that you have them in `NSArray` and that you're aware of `NSNumber` & [Objective-C Literals](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html). In other words, you have:

```c
NSArray *keys    = @[@1, @3, @5]; // Array of NSNumber
NSArray *objects = @[@2, @4, @6]; // Array of NSNumber
```

> "dictionary":{"1":2,: "3":4, "5":6}

I assume that it means:

```c
@{
    @"dictionary": @{
        @"1": @2,
        @"3": @4,
        @"5": @6
    }
}
```

### Step 1 - Stringify keys

```c
NSArray *keys = @[@1, @3, @5];
NSArray *objects = @[@2, @4, @6];

NSMutableArray *stringifiedKeys = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:keys.count];
for (NSNumber *key in keys) {
    [stringifiedKeys addObject:key.stringValue];
}
```

### Step 2 - Create a dictionary

[`dictionaryWithObjects:forKeys:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdictionary/1574183-dictionarywithobjects?language=objc):

```c
+ (instancetype)dictionaryWithObjects:(NSArray<ObjectType> *)objects 
                              forKeys:(NSArray<id<NSCopying>> *)keys;
```

You can use it in this way:

```c
NSArray *keys = @[@1, @3, @5];
NSArray *objects = @[@2, @4, @6];

NSMutableArray *stringifiedKeys = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:keys.count];
for (NSNumber *key in keys) {
    [stringifiedKeys addObject:key.stringValue];
}

NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects
                                                       forKeys:stringifiedKeys];
```

### Step 3 - Wrap it in a dictionary

```c
NSArray *keys = @[@1, @3, @5];
NSArray *objects = @[@2, @4, @6];

NSMutableArray *stringifiedKeys = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:keys.count];
for (NSNumber *key in keys) {
    [stringifiedKeys addObject:key.stringValue];
}

NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects
                                                       forKeys:stringifiedKeys];
NSDictionary *result = @{ @"dictionary": dictionary };

NSLog(@"%@", result);
```

Result:

```
{
    dictionary = {
        1 = 2;
        3 = 4;
        5 = 6;
    };
}
```

### Manually

```c
NSArray *keys = @[@1, @3, @5];
NSArray *objects = @[@2, @4, @6];

// Mimick dictionaryWithObjects:forKeys: behavior
if (objects.count != keys.count) {
    NSString *reason = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"count of objects (%lu) differs from count of keys (%lu)", (unsigned long)objects.count, (unsigned long)keys.count];

    @throw [NSException exceptionWithName:NSInvalidArgumentException
                                   reason:reason
                                 userInfo:nil];
}

NSMutableDictionary *inner = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:keys.count];

for (NSUInteger index = 0 ; index < keys.count ; index++) {
    NSString *key = [keys[index] stringValue];
    NSString *object = objects[index];
    inner[key] = object;
}

NSDictionary *result = @{ @"dictionary": inner };
```

### Footnotes

Because of *I am very new to Objective-C*, I did intentionally avoid:

- Blocks & safer ways to enumerate
- Lightweight generics
- Nullability stuff

Answer (score -2):

You can try it use this code:

```
- (NSDictionary *)convertToDicFromKeys:(NSArray *)keys andValues:(NSArray *)values
{

    NSInteger count = MIN(keys.count, values.count);
    NSMutableDictionary *dic = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:count];
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        dic[keys[i]] = values[i];
    }
    return dic;
}
```

Comment: Hi. I'm getting an error of `Expected method to read dictionary element not found on object of type 'NSMutableArray`

Comment: @jordanzee don't use this, it's wrong, especially this `dic[keys[i]] = dic[values[i]]` line. Use [`dictionaryWithObjects:forKeys:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdictionary/1574183-dictionarywithobjects?language=objc) as Larme already told you.