# Convert two NSarray to NSString

Tags: ios, arrays, json, objective-c

Hi so I have two NS Arrays in my view controller, with both the same number of count. btw this is for submitting for upload.

```
barcodeItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

barcodeItemsQuantity = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Once the arrays have been populated this method will be called,

```
-(void) performUploadOperation {
parameters = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

// Add barcodes and quantity
if (barcodeItems != nil || barcodeItemsQuantity != nil) {

    [parameters setValue:barcodeItems forKey:@"upc"];
    [parameters setValue:barcodeItemsQuantity forKey:@"upcQuantity"];

   }
}
```

Once this is submitted another method will be called to convert it to nsstring

```
NSArray* upc = [parameters objectForKey:@"upc"];
NSArray* upcQuantity = [parameters objectForKey:@"upcQuantity"];

NSString* sample = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"upc_list\" : { \"%@\": %@}}", upc, upcQuantity];
NSLog(@"%@", sample);
```

The result is this

```
{"upc_list" : { "(
    76239878,
    0827755090991,
    76239878
)": (
    12,
    23,
    32
)}}
```

and what I want to achieve is something like this. both arrays have the same count always

```
{"upc_list" : { "
   (
    "76239878" : 12,
    "0827755090991" : 23,
    "76239878" : 32
   )
 }}
```

Comment: I wonder if this is somehow related to your previous question  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62151077/two-nsarrays-combine-to-a-nsdictionary-with-alternating-values ... Same pattern - two arrays, dictionary with stringified keys, ... The previous question wasn't crystal clear and this one isn't either.

Comment: " called to convert it to nsstring": Why? Why printing it like that? What's the goal?

Answer (score 0):

@jordanzee: You can use the below code to get your expected result.

```
NSArray *upc = [parameters objectForKey:@"upc"];
NSArray *upcQuantity = [parameters objectForKey:@"upcQuantity"];

NSMutableDictionary *aMutDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
for(NSInteger aIndex = 0; aIndex < upc.count; aIndex++){
   [aMutDict setValue:upcQuantity[aIndex] forKey:upc[aIndex]];
}

NSString *sample = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"upc_list\" : %@}", aMutDict];
NSLog(@"%@", sample);
```